# get distinct value from NSmutablearray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

i have a `nsmutablearray` as is shown below. I would like to retrieve list value without redundancy. in this example i should retrive `10 20 30`

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"10",@"20",@"30",@"30",@"30",@"30",@"20", nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Transform the array into a set, and then back into an array.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];

NSArray *a = [set allObjects];
```

You can also have this new array sorted:

```
NSArray *a2 = [a sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Since iOS 5 you can use `-[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:]` which preserves the order:

```
NSArray *a2 = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array] array];
```

Comment: NSOrderedSet is available since iOS 5

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *withRedunecy = [[NSSet setWithArray: array] allObjects];
```

This will be the one way like you can create new `NSArray` which has no duplicate objects or you need to create a logic for getting unique objects like insert one by one with checking is it already present or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this on

```
NSArray *array = @[@"10",@"20",@"30",@"30",@"30",@"30",@"20"];

NSArray *newArray =  [[NSSet setWithArray:array] allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", newArray);
```

**Output : 
(
    30,
    20,
    10
)**

Answer (score 0):

Only this line of code will work fine .

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
```

now mySet will have unique elements.so create array with this set

```
NSArray *myarray = [mySet allObjects];
```